# weird error in production server on digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have the devise gem to enable authorisation and authentication of admin users to my web app. However once i try to access blog.xxxx.com/admins/sign_up i get an application error. Below are the contents of my production.log file

```
I, [2016-05-24T06:30:33.215786 #21746]  INFO -- : Started GET "/blog/xmlrpc.php" for 89.248.174.4 at 2016-05-24 06:30:33 -0400
F, [2016-05-24T06:30:33.220309 #21746] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/blog/xmlrpc.php"):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `call'
  puma (3.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you share your routes file? Specifically, the routes relevant to the question? What is the xmlrpc.php file that it is routing to?

Comment: As I wrote that error is not caused by you (unless you are trying to access `/blog/xmlrpc.php` on your app). I that really the only error in the logs? What do you see in the browser, when you try to get that `admin/sign_up` route?

Answer (score 3):

This log message is unrelated to your application or you trying to sign in.

It just tells you that someone tried to request the route `/blog/xmlrpc.php` and your application was not able to answer on that route. It is basically just a `404 not found` message.

Why to people (or bots) try to request `/blog/xmlrpc.php` on random servers? Because the `/blog/xmlrpc.php` route allows attacks against some Wordpress versions. And an attacker is searching for victoms by scanning IP ranges.

It is safe to ignore this kind of requests. The only think you might want to ensure is that your application is correctly configured and responses with a proper `404 not found` (not a `500 internal server error`).

Comment: hi @spickermann how do i get rid of it since i'm accessing a route that works on my development server but doesn't on the production server

Answer (score 1):

Simply someone is trying to call some URLs of your website to find... Well, something. It might be even a bot. Anyway, this is not a problem at all.